# Codeigniter - extending controller does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, extending

I am trying to extend a controller with my own class which extends the default CI_Controller class. Except it doesn't work.

It says it can't find my sub-class. My subclass is located in application/core and is named My_Control_Panel.

My class that extends on my sub-class:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Developers extends My_Control_Panel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();

        $this->checkIfLoggedIn();
        $this->checkIfAllowedToViewPage();
}
```

My sub-class:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_Control_Panel extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

It keeps saying it can't find my sub-class, while it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should name your file like this `My_Controller.php` inside your `core` folder
and then you type your code like

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_Control_Panel extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and this is the right way to do it in CodeIgniter, not as mentioned in the first answer with the include one ..

Comment: yes but its the `application/core` which we are talking about here not the `system/core` .. [check the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: can I rename the My_Controller.php file into something like My_Form.php?

Comment: no you cants, since this is related to your Controllers, but if you want to extend CI_Form, then yes you can Call it My_Form

Answer (score 3):

If you want CI to pick up your extended class you will have to name it `MY_Controller`. The `MY_` part is configurable, but the other parts are not.

The `MY_` part comes form the `config/config.php:`

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried changing it and stuff, but it couldn't find my sub-class anyhow

Comment: This usually ends up beeing a lower/uppercase problem, your example has `My` with lowercase `y`. Maybe that's the reason. (or could be your config has `My_`)

Comment: Sorry about that, was a copy mistake. :) In my code it is MY_

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to include the parent class (`My_Control_Panel`) in the subclass (`Developers`), like so:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once '../path/to/mycontrolpanel.php';

class Developers extends My_Control_Panel
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: But that wasn't mentioned in de userguide of CodeIgniter. Are you sure this is the correct way?

Comment: It works for me to, but I still doubt this is best way. Thank anyhow. :)